# Issue writing Count SQL query and displaying results

Tags: sql

I am having an issue converting this query into a Count query, is anyone able to help. I basically want to count the number of records returned for this date, and ideally show it in a table that says Database Name and then total count.
E.G. In this example would be Test then 6

```
SELECT
    test.dbo.OrderedDocuments.UserDocumentID, 
    OrderedDocuments.OrderGroupID, OrderGroups.TimePlaced 
FROM
    OrderedDocuments 
INNER JOIN 
    OrderGroups ON OrderedDocuments.OrderGroupID = OrderGroups.OrderGroupID
WHERE 
    OrderGroups.TimePlaced > '2018-05-17'
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: What problem are you having?  Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

If, you want to display count then use `count()` function :

For instance :

```
SELECT count(*) Total_count
FROM  OrderedDocuments 
INNER JOIN OrderGroups 
           ON OrderedDocuments.OrderGroupID = OrderGroups.OrderGroupID
WHERE OrderGroups.TimePlaced >'2018-05-17';
```

If, you want to get *departmental* count then use `GROUP BY` clause to get *departmental* count

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding (assuming UserDocumentID is the field you want to see the counts of) you would want to do this:

```
SELECT od.UserDocumentID, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM  OrderedDocuments od
INNER JOIN OrderGroups og
   ON od.OrderGroupID = og.OrderGroupID
WHERE og.TimePlaced >'2018-05-17'
GROUP BY od.UserDocumentID
```